# Unexpected gc alloc behavior in linkedList.find()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

As we all know that if we compare a value type variable with null,it will cause GC alloc cause of boxing:

```
{
    public class TestGeneric<T>{

        public static bool TestGC(T key)
        {
            return key == null;
        }
    }
    TestGeneric<int>.TestGC(10);
}
```

However, I found that the Find(T value) method of LinkedList(System.Collections.Generic) used same code like

```
public LinkedListNode<T> Find(T value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

But the calling like

```
//LinkedList<int> list;
list.Find(10);
```

**will NOT cause any GC alloc.**

I am really confused about that. Any body got an idea? Please Help.Thanks a lot.

====================

Test enviroment: Unity 2018, Unity Profiler(Deep Profile Enable) **.Net Version:4.0**

Here is my test code.

```
public class TestGeneric<T> {

    public static bool TestGC(T key)
    {
        return key == null;
    }
}

public class LinkedListTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>();
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            list.AddLast(i);
        }
    }
    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            TestGeneric<int>.TestGC(10);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            list.Find(100);
        }
    }
}
```

The unity profiler shows

**TestGC method caused 200Byte GC Alloc per frame.**

**list.Find method caused 0Byte GC Alloc per frame.**

Comment: Heres the implementation : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,a8a85c5fb1a25488

Comment: It uses `if(match(_items[i])) ` to compare values and I'm not sure what that does :D

Comment: @Milos, it seems you pointed to List implementation, not LinkedList...

Comment: Oh, my bad. Heres the LinkedList one https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,74e4e6394382badc,references

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `LinkedList<T>.Find` (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,74e4e6394382badc,references)

uses `EqualityComparer<T>` to compare values, which in turn uses `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netframework-4.8)

which

> When the Equals method is called and the other argument is a strongly-typed object of type T. (If other is not of type T, the base Object.Equals(Object) method is called. Of the two methods, IEquatable.Equals offers slightly better performance.)

Since you are comparing int and they are the same type, the boxing does not occur since Object.Equals is not called.

Comment: Firstly it still uses `if (value != null)` and also Unity doesn't use this version of `LinkeList` as it uses Mono libraries but the condition is still used there.